# Modo de adicionar ícone ao Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, image, icons

Estive realizando pesquisas na internet sobre a implementação de ícones para aplicativos android pelo android studio, porém, confesso que fiquei  um tanto confuso.

Fiz meu ícone usando o Adobe Illustrator em um projeto de 192x192 pixels, porém ao invés de exportar várias medidas drawable  pelo mesmo estou exportando  somente o 1x e assim adicionando esse pelo image asset do Android studio para ele criar as imagens de outras resoluções.

A maneira que escolhi fazer é correta? Ocorre algum prejuízo na  visualização final da imagem em todas as resoluções?

Comment: Resposta curta: É a maneira correcta.

Comment: Vc pode usar um "Gerador de Icones" para colocar a sua imagem em todos os formatos que precisa. Essa por exemplo funciona bem com o Cordova http://pgicons.abiro.com/ as vezes pode te ajudar

Answer (score 0):

Está correto, mas ícones normalmente são feitos pelo vector asset, pois eles, na sua maioria, são vetores. Só é preciso tomar cuidado com algumas propriedades do ícone exportado que não podem funcionar em API's mais antigas. Por exemplo ,existe uma função de gradiente de cor no xml que só dá certo em API's superiores a 24. 
Enfim, o jeito de exportar está correto. 
Faz o ícone no software que desejar, exporta para .png ou .svg e usa o image asset OU vector asset (que é voltado justamente para os ícones vetorizados).

Answer (score -2):

É como o colega acima falou. O ideal é o vector asset, porém vai depender da api mínima do projeto, se for api 20 para baixo teria que usar png mesmo porque não são compatíveis com drawables vetoriais, 21 pra cima já pode utilizar o vector asset, apenas alguns pormenores como o gradiente supracitado.

A cargo de conhecimento, eu utilizo o .svg e gero através do vector asset os ícones que utilizo nos meus projetos